# Can't validate children of a has_many through relation directly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following setup:

```rb
class Round < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards_rounds
  has_many :cards, through: :cards_rounds
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :cards_rounds

  validate :round_validations

  private

  def round_validations
    // pry
    unless cards.map(&:id).uniq.size == 3
      errors.add(:round, "Must have 3 unique cards")
    end
    unless cards.map(&:quality).uniq.size == 1
      errors.add(:round, "Cards must be of the same rarity")
    end
  end
end

class CardsRound < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :card
  belongs_to :round
end

class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :cards_rounds
  has_many :rounds, through: :cards_rounds
end
```

`Round` always fails to validate on creation. When I step in using pry, I can see that `cards` is nil, but `cards_rounds` is populated and I can call `cards_rounds[0].card` (for example).

Is this the expected behaviour? It seems odd to me that I can reference the cards through cards_rounds but not directly as a collection.

Rails version is 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I feel your pain. I'm not sure if this is the expected behavior but I've came into this same problem some times.

The best think you can do is to open an issue on https://github.com/rails/rails

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where the problem is, I did the following gist which the tests pass: https://gist.github.com/arthurnn/9607180. See that I changed the validation. The problem is that the validation cannot rely on mapping the ids from cards, as they dont have an id yet.